# Linking Subdomain to Shared Windows Business Hosting

Tags: godaddy, shared-hosting, asp.net, sql-server

I have my main domain on GoDaddy.
And have purchased a Business Shared Windows Hosting from BigRock as GoDaddy has only 200mb limit on MS SQL DB.

How can I link a subdomain I create on my main domain to the Business Shared Windows Hosting on BigRock; so that **all my ASP.NET source code & MS SQL Database will be on BigRock** (Business Shared Windows Hosting) however, **it will be accessible via the subdomain (GoDaddy)**

Comment: Besides any DNS settings, are you also asking how to point your asp code to the new DB server?

Comment: @closetnoc Yes, only regarding DNS settings. not about linking my code to use DB.

Comment: Cool! Just checking! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Create the subdomain at GoDaddy *and* at Bigrock.

At GoDaddy change the A record of only the subdomain to point to the IP address of the BigRock server.

That's all you need to do.

Comment: [qoute]Create the subdomain at GoDaddy and at Bigrock.[/qoute] .................Is creating Subdomain on my BigRock account possible? I only have the Business Shared Windows Hosting, and no domains.

Comment: You're asking me?

Comment: I understood the part of changes to be made at GoDaddy. You mentioned creating subdomain at Bigrock too. However, at BigRock account I only have hosting[Business Windows Hosting]. Hence, asking if that is possible.

Comment: Again...how would I know?  If you have hosting you likely have a management area (cpanel? Plesk?).  You would do it in there.  Or...and here's a novel idea...you would contact BigRock tech support.